# How to connect grouped points in ggplot within groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataset with two groups - Experimental and Control. Each participant contributes two responses per group, which represent different learning styles. These are represented in the box plots with jitter below. I would like to connect each participant's two responses together with lines using ggplot (so each red line in the Control group would correspond to each turquoise line in the control group), however I can't figure out how to do this within the conditions. Can someone please help? I am new to R and really need guidance.

Then, I need to change the color of the lines within the conditions to black if Increase = TRUE and red if Increase = FALSE.

Ideally, I need it to look like Jon's example here, but with black or red lines based on True or False: [Connecting grouped points with lines in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407648/connecting-grouped-points-with-lines-in-ggplot)

The data and ggplot looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame (
  Subject = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  Group  = c("Exp", "Exp", "Control", "Control"),
  Tr = c("14", "11", "4", "23"),
  Sr = c("56", "78", "12", "10"),
  Increase = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
)

# put the data in long format
d <- d %>%
  gather(key = "Strategy", value = "raw", Tr, Sr)

d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = raw, color = Strategy)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, lwd = 0.5) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.15) +
  geom_line(aes(group = raw),
            color = "grey",
            arrow = arrow(type = "closed",
                          length = unit(0.075, "inches")))
```

Comment: Please share sample data as copy/pasteable code in valid R syntax, not as a screenshot of a table. `dput()` is a great command for that, `dput(data[1:12, ])` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first 12 rows of data including all class and structure information.

Comment: From the picture of your data, it's not clear what points should be connected. Is there an ID column or something to indicate which pairs of points go together?

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. I just added a copy/pasteable code - is that better?

Comment: The points that need to be connected are the Tr and Sr per each subject in each Exp and Ctr group. So for the first one, the points that need to be connected within the Exp group are 14 and 23

Comment: This is much clearer. `position_jitterdodge` works well for point and boxplot [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48954358/903061), but with lines also I think the only option is to jitter manually - adding the noise as columns in your data. I don't have time to write an answer up now, but later this evening if no one else has answered I'll try to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. I looked at the example above and the position_jitterdodge worked well, however I still can't get it to connect the two values per subject in each Ctr and Exp group. I am not sure what you mean by adding the noise as columns in the data, can you kindly clarify or add an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I wanted to suggest an alternative visualisation.

You are dealing with paired data. A much more convincing visualisation is achieved with a scatter plot. You will use the two dimensions of your paper rather than mapping your two dimensions onto only one. You can compare control with subjects better and see immediately which one got better or worse.

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame (
  Subject = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  Group  = c("Exp", "Exp", "Control", "Control"),
  Tr = c("14", "11", "4", "23"),
  Sr = c("56", "78", "12", "10"),
  Increase = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
)  %>%
## convert to numeric first
mutate(across(c(Tr,Sr), as.integer))

## set coordinate limits
lims <- range(c(d$Tr, d$Sr))

ggplot(d) +
  geom_point(aes(Tr, Sr, color = Group)) +
## adding a line of equality and setting limits equal helps guide the eye
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, lty = "dashed") +
  coord_equal(xlim = lims , ylim = lims )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from the answer you linked to - [@Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408429/9049673)

There are a few key things to understand the solution

1. Since you need points and lines to be connected, you need them both to apply the exact same random jitter or it is best to jitter the data before it goes into plotting which is what I did.
2. Since the variable to apply jitter on is not a number, it is helpful to note that R plots the character vector `Group` as a factor, interpreted as numbers 1,2,3,.. corresponding to the factor levels. Hence we create a numeric vector group_jit with values around 1 and 2, with offsets based on the colouring variable `Strategy` to shift slightly left and right around 1 and 2.
3. Since you have two independent colour scales going on, it is best to have the Groups represented as `fill` and the lines represented as `colour` to avoid a single legend with 4 things on it.

Here's the code -

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Load data
d <- data.frame (
  Subject = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  Group  = c("Exp", "Exp", "Control", "Control"),
  Tr = c("14", "11", "4", "23"),
  Sr = c("56", "78", "12", "10"),
  Increase = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
)

width_jitter <- 0.2 # 1 means full width between points

# put the data in long format
d_jit <- d %>%
  gather(key = "Strategy", value = "raw", Tr, Sr) %>% 
  
  # type conversions
  mutate(across(c(Group, Strategy), as_factor)) %>% # convert to factors
  mutate(raw = as.numeric(raw)) %>% # make raw as numbers
  
  # position on x axis is based on combination of Group and jittered Strategy. Mix to taste.
  mutate(group_jit = as.numeric(Group) + jitter(as.numeric(Strategy) - 1.5) * width_jitter * 2,
         grouping = interaction(Subject, Strategy))

# plotting
d_jit %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Group, y = raw, fill = Strategy)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, lwd = 0.5, alpha = 0.05, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = group_jit), size = 3, shape = 21) +
  
  geom_line(aes(x = group_jit,
                group = Subject,
                colour = Increase),
            alpha = 0.5,
            arrow = arrow(type = "closed",
                          length = unit(0.075, "inches"))
            ) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red', 'black'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

For completeness sake, a different, and more elegant way to to do the jitter is to give a `position` argument to the `geom_point` and `geom_line` commands. This argument is a function which adds the random jitter like this (source: [@erocoar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48955258/9049673))

```
position = ggplot2::position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.75, jitter.width = 0.3, seed = 1)
```

This way the data itself is not changed and the plotting takes care of the jittering details

- `jitterdodge` does the dodge (shift for the x axis variable) and jitter (small noise for the coloured points)
- The `seed` argument here is key since it ensures that the same *random* values are returned for the point and the line functions that call it independently

Comment: Thank you so much, Prashant! This is exactly what I needed! The example is really clear and the explanations really helped me understand what I needed to do. Much appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome! If the question has been answered satisfactorily, could you `accept` it by clicking on the check box on the top left so that the question is marked settled for future people finding this post, Thanks!