# Plotting paired data for multiple groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I want to ask how to plot paired data connected with lines in ggplot across multiple groups? Some sample data to work with:

```
set.seed(123)
sample <- data.frame(name = c(rep("Amy",4),rep("Bob",4),rep("Jack",4)),
                     status = rep(c("Before","After"),6),
                     test = rep(c("English","English","Math","Math"),3),
                     score = sample(60:100,12,replace=T))
sample %>% ggplot(aes(x=test,y=score,fill=status)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + geom_point(size = 2)
```

The idea is to have the `test` on the x-axis and `score` on the y axis as shown below but instead of having a boxplot, the individual `geom_point()` are stratified by `status` group (so points that are in the `after` group are in the space where the red boxplot is and points that are in the `before` group are in the space where the blue boxplot is) with `geom_line()` connecting the paired data points from the same `name`. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to make "status" the x-aesthetic and to use facet wrap to separate the tests:

```
ggplot(sample, aes(x = status, y = score)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill = status), alpha = .2) +
geom_line(aes(group = name)) + 
geom_point(size = 2) + 
facet_wrap(~ test)
```

[image: Plot with boxplot and line]

If you don't need the boxplots, you can move the "group" aesthetic to the first line.

```
ggplot(sample, aes(x = status, y = score, group = name)) + 
geom_line() + 
geom_point(size = 2, aes(color = status)) + 
facet_wrap(~ test, switch = "x") +
scale_x_discrete("") +
theme_minimal() +
theme(legend.position = "top", 
      panel.grid = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.line.y = element_line(size = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, faceting does work in this case, I'd still just like to ask would you know a solution that keeps everything on the same plot since in the real dataset I actually have more groups and ideally I would plot something that looks like figure 2E in this publication: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-11788-4

Comment: I think that it depends what you need: If you want to create this type of plot more regularly, you might google for a specific package for creating slope plots. If you want to learn about ggplot, you might also look into how to modify the themes. You can use facetting with multiple groups and you can make the facetting less obvious creating an almost identical plot.