# Plotting regression lines on scatterplot w/ x axis as categorical variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I would like to add a regression line between the two categorical variables on the x- axis for all the dots in the plot. I want to visualize the trend essentially between the two temperatures. Each color represents a gene and each x categorical variable is a temp. Expression or amplitude is on the y axis. I just want one regression line that summarizes all of the data between the two temperatures.[image: Example]

Comment: Try with `geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = lm, se = FALSE)`. For more help we need [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a working example of your code and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656299/lines-connecting-jittered-points-dodging-by-multiple-groups#comment76300573_44656299 which discusses a very related visualisation and for an idea of showing your data in a more intuitive way