# add geom_line to link all the geom_point in boxplot conditioned on a factor with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a patient data something like below. Each subject are measured at 4 different time points.

```
df <- data.frame(
    result = rnorm(48, 1,3),
    time = rep(c('t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'), 12  ),
    subject = rep(c(1:12), each=4),
    gender = rep (c('M', 'F'), 6, each=4) )
```

I made a boxplot with overlaying datapoints:

```
pd = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.75, jitter.width = 0.3)
df %>% 
    ggplot (aes(x= time, y=result, fill=gender))+
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2)+
    geom_point(aes(color = gender),position = pd)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1')+
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

Now I need to add lines to link all patients (data points) along the time course.

```
df %>% 
    ggplot (aes(x= time, y=result, fill=gender))+
    geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2)+
    geom_point(aes(color = gender, group=subject),position = pd)+
    geom_line(aes(color=gender, group=subject), 
    position=pd, alpha=0.3)+
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1')+
    scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

[image]

All the lines seems to 'disconnected from data points. How can I fix this problem? I have spent hours but could not find solution. Could anyone kindly help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem is something about how position interacts with points vs. lines. I assume the jitter is necessary, since it works if you take it out? Sorry I couldn't be more helpful . . .

Comment: @Henrik   I tried the method from the link. But the problem is I have a extra factor.  I could not figure out how to make it work

Comment: [Combining geom_point and geom_line with position_jitterdodge in ggplot2 for two grouping factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020435/combining-geom-point-and-geom-line-with-position-jitterdodge-in-ggplot2-for-two)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some days ago `position_jitterdodge` [gained a seed argument](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commit/39e4a3bdb910a0344e2f75a5ade2e4f27e263a62) in the development version. So,

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
```

and then

```
pd = ggplot2::position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.75, jitter.width = 0.3, seed = 1)
df %>% 
  ggplot (aes(x= time, y=result, fill=gender))+
  geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2)+
  geom_point(aes(color = gender, group=subject),position = pd)+
  geom_line(aes(color=gender, group=subject), 
            position=pd, alpha=0.3)+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1')+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1')
```

gives this plot

[image]

Comment: sorry for a followup question. I notice there are always two point with grey color at the middle top and lower right respectively. Do you know why? how do I get ride of that? thank you!  @erocoar

Comment: That should be fixed when you replace your boxplot argument with `geom_boxplot(alpha=0.2, outlier.shape = NA)` :)

Comment: I found one problem with this. The points are not aligned with the same color box. Anyway to adjust that?

Comment: Yes, I see the problem now :/ It is that for the `geom_point` you need `group=gender`, whereas for the `geom_segment` you need `group=subject`. I think manual jittering will be the only way to go in that case, since the order of drawing (and so jitter) will be different for the two geoms