# Pairing Scatter Points with Lines Across Fill Condition of Violin Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

Here is a data.frame with three subjects in a 2 by 2 design:

```
x<-data.frame("sub" = rep(c("sub1","sub2","sub3"),times=4),
          "cond1" = rep(c("A","B"),times=c(6,6)),
          "cond2" = rep(c("C","C","C","D","D","D"),times=2),
          "score" = c(6,5,4, 5,4,3, 4,3,2, 3,2,1))
```

Here is the split violin plot (for function, https://gist.github.com/Karel-Kroeze/746685f5613e01ba820a31e57f87ec87):

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width=.5)
ggplot(x, aes(x=cond1, y=score, fill=cond2))+
  geom_split_violin(trim = F)+
  geom_point(shape=16,position=dodge)
```

[image: 2 by 2 split violin plot]

What I would like to do is connect the individual subject scatter points with a line across the fill condition (e.g., sub1 in cond1 A and cond2 C will connect to sub1 in cond1 A and cond2 D). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I think this may be related: [Combining geom_point and geom_line with position_jitterdodge in ggplot2 for two grouping factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020435/combining-geom-point-and-geom-line-with-position-jitterdodge-in-ggplot2-for-two)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach. First, I `spread` the table so the beginning and end of `geom_segment` can be based on different columns. Then I convert the `cond1` values to numeric (which is what ggplot does under the hood) and feed those into the x fields. The x dodge offset of 0.12 was manual, but there's probably a clever way (beyond my current understanding) to use the ggplot settings to determine that automatically.

```
library(tidyverse)
dodge <- position_dodge(width=.5)
ggplot(x, aes(x=cond1, y=score, fill=cond2))+
  geom_split_violin(trim = F)+
  geom_point(shape=16,position=dodge) +
  geom_segment(data = x %>% spread(cond2, score),
               aes(x    = as.numeric(cond1) - 0.12, 
                   xend = as.numeric(cond1) + 0.12,
                   y = C, yend = D), inherit.aes = FALSE, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like ggplot2 has changed behavior during numeric conversion from character. It needs now to be previously converted to a factor. 
`aes(x    = as.numeric(as.factor(cond1)) - 0.12, xend = as.numeric(as.factor(cond1)) + 0.12,`