# Connecting means with stat_summary (geom = 'line') within ticks on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to create a plot in ggplot2 similar to this one:
[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dataset %>% 
  group_by(Participant, Group, Emotion) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Score, x = Emotion, fill = Group, colour = Group)) +
  geom_flat_violin(position = position_nudge(x = .2, y = 0), alpha = .4) +
  geom_point(aes(y = Score, color = Group), position = position_jitter(width = .15), size = 3, alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_summary(aes(y = Score, group = Emotion), fun.y = mean, geom="line", size = 2.2, alpha = 1.2, width = 0.25, colour = 'gray48') +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'pointrange', width = 0.2, size = 2, alpha = 1.2, position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom='errorbar', width = 0.25, size = 2.2, alpha = 1.2, linetype = "solid",position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  ylim(0, 100) +
  graph_theme
```

What I am failing to do is **set up the stat_summary(geom = 'line') to connect the green and orange means within each emotion** on the x-axis. Could anyone give any pointers on this? I'd also like all the other features to stay the same if possible (e.g., I wouldn't like to use facet_grid or facet_wrap).

Thank you!

When I change the group argument in stat_summary to 'Group' instead of 'Emotion', means for each group are connected across emotions, but I can't figure out how to connect means of different groups within each emotion:
[image]

Comment: Change `group = Emotion` to `group = Group`

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for answering! This doesn't do the job - when I do this, I get two lines (one for each group) connecting means of the same group across emotions. I will add how the graph looks in the post above.

Comment: Maybe `group = 1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `geom_line` to the same position as `pointrange` and `errorbar` will solve the problem.
i.e.,

```
stat_summary(aes(y = Score, group = Emotion), fun.y = mean, geom="line", size = 2.2, alpha = 1.2, width = 0.25, colour = 'gray48', position=position_dodge(width=0.3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one because your `line` needs to connect points that have different `x` values but even if you jitter in the `point` layer, they still technically have the same `x` value so the line doesn't know how to connect them. What others have done is to manually add the jitter to force the points to have a different `x` position. For more inspiration check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44657850/13210554), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533567/13210554) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37022723/13210554). Here's an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

emotion <- c("anger", "fear", "sadness")
group <- letters[1:2]
participant <- 1:10

dat <- expand_grid(emotion, group, participant) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.factor),
         score = sample(x = 1:100, size = nrow(.), replace = T))


dat %>% 
  mutate(new_emot = case_when(
    group == "a" ~as.numeric(emotion) - 0.125,
    group == "b" ~as.numeric(emotion) + 0.125
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = emotion, y = score)) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = group), fun = mean, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(aes(color = group), fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = new_emot, group = emotion), fun = mean, geom = "line") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>